# Mocking an Autowired Webservice using Mockito/EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class as follows:

```
@Component
public class UserAuthentication {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationWebService authenticationWebservice;

    public boolean authenticate(username, password) {

    result = authenticationWebService.authenticateUser(username, password)

    //do
    //some
    //logical
    //things
    //here

    return result;
   }
}
```

I am writing a unit test to see if the function behaves correctly. Now ofcourse I am not suppose to do an actual webservice call. So how can I mock the webservice in such a way that when I call the authenticate method of my class, the mocked webservice object is used instead of the real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mockito you stub the external service like this:

```
'when(mockedAuthenticationWebService.authenticate(username, password).thenReturn(yourStubbedReturnValue);'
```

I am writing this up from memory so forgive if it doesn't compile straight away; you'll get the idea.

Here, using Mockito, hamcrest and JUnit 4, I am also verifying that the service is called with the correct parameters, which your test will want to cover as well :)

```
@Test
public class UserAuthenticationTest { 
     // Given 
     UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(); 
     AuthenticationWebService mockedAuthenticationWebService = mock(AuthenticationWebService.class)

     String username = "aUsername" , password = "aPassword";
     when(mockedAuthenticationWebService.authenticate(username, password).thenReturn(true); // but you could return false here too if your test needed it

     userAuthentication.set(mockedAuthenticationWebService); 

     // When  
     boolean yourStubbedReturnValue = userAuthentication.authenticate(username, password); 

     //Then 
    verify(mockedAuthenticationWebService).authenticateUser(username, password); 
    assertThat(yourStubbedReturnValue, is(true));
}
```

Lastly, the fact that your class is @Autowired makes no difference to any of this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@ContextConfiguration` annotation in your test class.

Doing so Spring will load context configuration from `classpath:/foo.bar/spring/test/...xml`

In that `context.xml` file from `/test/` you can create mock objects and Spring will inject them instead of real ones.

You can find many tutorials if you need step-by-step guide, just search for `Spring @ContextConfiguration` (I don't include links since they may change in time).